# How to add conditionals inside shell expressions?

Tags: javascript, linux, shell

I have the following JavaScript script:

```
exec('(echo "<!doctype html><html><body><script>" && browserify --ig '+file+'.js '+(minify ? '| uglifyjs'+(compress ? ' -c' : '') : '')+' && echo "</script></body></html>") > '+file+'.html')
```

I want to translate it to ShellScript alone. How do I translate the ternary operators, though?

Answer (score 0):

To translate ternary operators to shell script, you will need to use if statements.  I don't think shell scripting has anything like a ternary operator.

If you need to know the syntax for the if statement, look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/if-elif-statement.htm).